# Accessing class members that are arrays through "pointers to class members"

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have written below code to explore pointers to class members:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Sample{
    public:
        int i;
        char name[35];
        char* City;

        Sample(int i,const char* ptr,const char* addr):i(i){
            strncpy(name,ptr,35);
            City= (char*) malloc(strlen(addr)*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(City,addr);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Sample Ob1(1,"Andrew Thomas","Glasgow");
    cout << Ob1.i << " : " << Ob1.name << " lives at : "<< (Ob1.City)<< endl;
    int Sample::*FI=&Sample::i;
    char* Sample::*FCity= &Sample::City;
    char* Sample::*FName=  &Sample::name;

    cout << Ob1.*FI << endl;
    cout << Ob1.*FCity << endl;
    cout << Ob1.*FName << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error for `char* Sample::*FName=  &Sample::name;` as below:

```
$ g++ -Wall ExploreGDB.cpp -o ExploreGDB
ExploreGDB.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ExploreGDB.cpp:28:34: error: cannot convert ‘char (Sample::*)[35]’ to ‘char* Sample::*’ in initialization
  char* Sample::*FName=  &Sample::name;
                                  ^
```

The rest of the code works fine.

Can anyone let me know how to declare a pointer to data member declared as -`char name[35];`?

Comment: If you're using c++ use std::string instead of char* to store text, it will save you hassle in the long run.

Comment: `Sample`'s constructor has a problem overflow if the string pointed to by `ptr` is longer than 34

Comment: I was just trying to explore `pointer to character array`, hence this code else `string` is safest for C++

Comment: @MattMcNabb I suppose it is going to extract `34 characters` from `ptr` and store at `name` .. Though I Forgot to write as `City= (char*) malloc((strlen(addr)+1)*sizeof(char));` considering null character.. But Still it will ignore `characters beyond 34 in ptr while storing at name` .. So How is there a possibility of overflow at `name` as it is storing `34 chars + null character` i.e. only `35 characters`

Comment: @Gaurav, it extracts 35 characters and doesn't null-terminate if there are that many, but presumably the rest of your code expects a null-terminated string

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have not taken care of Null-Termination as i was just trying to explore pointers to class members.. Suppose my code takes care of `null-termination` in each string i.e. `34 characters it copies from ptr and then adds null`.. In that case I do not see any overflow in  `name` array- with using `strncpy`.. Only thing it is going to miss characters beyond 34 in `ptr`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the pointer as follows:

```
char (Sample::*FName)[35]=  &Sample::name;
```

The general rule is that `U (T::*<var_name>)` declares pointer to a member of class `T` with type `U`. Here, the type is `char <var_name>[35]`, so the syntax above is required.

Also note, your `malloc` is incorrect. `strlen` gives the number of characters in the string, but to represent that, you need one more character for the terminating null char:

```
City= (char*) malloc(strlen(addr)+1);
strcpy(City,addr);
```